# My Dynamic Table keeps repeating the titles with each new database entry

Tags: php, html, mysql, content-management-system, dreamweaver

I am trying to create Dynamic tables using the Repeat Region in Dreamweaver cs5 but unfortunately, upon viewing on the browser, each new record entry repeats the titles too.

- **COMPANY      REF        DATE**
      highbury     223333    2014-02-01
      **COMPANY      REF         DATE**
      anfield     223335    2014-02-03
     **COMPANY       REF         DATE**
      trafford     223336    2014-02-02

How can i have the the table showing the  title only once with the respective entry below it?
i.e.,

- **COMPANY      REF        DATE**
      highbury    223333    2014-02-01
      anfield     223334    2014-02-03
      trafford    223336    2014-02-02

Here is the html/php markup.

```
<?php require_once('Connections/connect.php'); ?>
<?php
if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
  if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
    $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
  }

  $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

  switch ($theType) {
    case "text":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;    
    case "long":
    case "int":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "double":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "date":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;
    case "defined":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
      break;
  }
  return $theValue;
}
}

mysql_select_db($database_connect, $connect);
$query_field = "SELECT * FROM field";
$field = mysql_query($query_field, $connect) or die(mysql_error());
$row_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($field);
$totalRows_field = mysql_num_rows($field);
?>

<?php do { ?>
  <table class="table table-hover table-nomargin">
    <thead>
      <tr>
       <th>Company</th>
       <th>Ref No.</th>
       <th>Date</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
     <tr>
      <td><?php echo $row_field['i_company']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row_field['i_ref']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row_field['i_date']; ?></td>
     </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
 <?php } while ($row_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($field)); ?>
```

Comment: Why did you uncheck my answer?

Comment: Sorry, mate1... i may have done that accidentally, as i thought u could 'check' on all correct answers!...again, sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move your do while statement to just the table records...

```
 <table class="table table-hover table-nomargin">
    <thead>
      <tr>
       <th>Company</th>
       <th>Ref No.</th>
       <th>Date</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
<?php do { ?>
     <tr>
      <td><?php echo $row_field['i_company']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row_field['i_ref']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row_field['i_date']; ?></td>
     </tr>
 <?php } while ($row_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($field)); ?>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Do/While function is telling the first row with the header to run for every row it finds in the data base. Try wrapping the Do/While function around the row that has the variables only, like this:

```
<table class="table table-hover table-nomargin">
<thead>
  <tr>
   <th>Company</th>
   <th>Ref No.</th>
   <th>Date</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

<?php do { ?>
 <tr>
  <td><?php echo $row_field['i_company']; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row_field['i_ref']; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row_field['i_date']; ?></td>
 </tr>
<?php } while ($row_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($field)); ?>

</tbody>
</table>
```

This way it will just repeat on that row, and not duplicate the header.